# Acer aspire m5 stuck in a restart loop that turns on and off in 5 seconds without any display

Tags: boot, bios, shutdown, reboot, infinite-loop

Hello my acer aspire m5 is stuck in a restart loop. Each time i switch it on it starts for 2 seconds then switsches off and on again. When it switches on you can feel the fan and drive running then they stop.sometimes during this restarts loops the laptop turns on and stays like for 5 minutes then shuts down. Its been like this for a while now. I have tried many methods such as removing all drives and even disconecting the internal battery and holding the power for 5 seconds but nothing works.the same problem had happened 8 months ago then after a while it worked better till now. Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Shut down, start up and right away press the BIOS access key (often F1 - check what it is for your machine). Does it start in BIOS?

If so, try starting with a bootable USB key (Windows 10 or Linux).

If these do not work, then the Motherboard / CPU is the most likely suspect.

If these tests do work, then the hard drive is a likely suspect.

See if the machine is worth repairing, or now is the time for a better machine.